# Bad line 13 in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, fstab

I'm new to Ubuntu and I've been trying to mount a NAS drive. In the process it looks like I have stuffed up my `/etc/fstab`. I now get unable to mount drive 0 when I boot up my VM/ubuntu, it asks me to proceed to mount manually or skip, (I choose skip).

When I run the command `mount -a` it tells me line 13 is bad.

Please see below:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=027ef0b9-53f8-4a08-94fa-4d0cd9c59b86 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 
0 0
//192.168.0.21/videoii /media/c3po-videoii cifs credentials=/home/coolhandluke/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have values for `dump` and `pass` parameters (`0` and `0` respectively in your case) in the 13th line which should be in the 12th line after initial declaration. Just move those two in the 12th line after declaration like:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```